# date conversion not working in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

jquery

```
 $("#Birthdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "+0D"
    });
```

cshtml

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Birthdate)<span style="color:red;">*</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Birthdate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Birthdate", style = "width: 100%;text-transform:capitalize;", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.Birthdate) })
&nbsp;@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Birthdate)
```

model

```
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Birthdate { get; set; }
```

following work fine

> selected date from jquery datepicker like `03/04/2016(dd/MM/YYYY)` then it saved in database
>   like `04/03/2016(MM/dd/YYYY)`

but tried like

> `28/04/2016` then it shows error Please check image

Error

[image]

***What is missing in my code .
Please guide me***

Comment: What is the culture on your server (it is nothing one that accepts dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`). And you need to re-configure the `jquery.validator` to for client side validation.

Comment: Note also since your using a jquery datepicker, the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attributes are not required (and in anycase it would need to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" in order to work with `<input type="date" ...`

Comment: my server date format is 'M/d/yyyy'  Is it needs to change and input type is text I used jquery datepicker

Comment: You need to change one or the other so they match (or you need to create a custom model binder to convert the posted format (dd/MM/yyyy) to `MM/dd/yyyy)`

Comment: I changed server format in MM/dd/yyyy but error showing same

Comment: No. Your client is sending a date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. The culture in your serer needs to be changed to match. For example, in the web.config file - `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />` (in the `<system.web>` section)

Comment: I removed both DataType and DisplayFormat  and added  globalization  in web.confiq but still showing error  Is their problem with database type date because I am using type date in database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141268/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-pravin).